# Get Value of Input Field on User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a User Control with an input filed.

```
<input type="text" name="firstName1" id="txtFirst1" />
```

I am trying to obtain the value enterd by the user from the code behind page. I do not want to add the property runat="server" to the field.

I have tried using the following code, but with no luck:

```
Dim MyFistName As String = Request.Form("txtFirst1")
```

How can I get the value of the input field txtFirst1 without adding runat="server"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

`Request.Form['txtFirst1']`

i.e. (C#):

`string inputValue = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form['txtFirst1']);`

Comment: I've tried using the C# example (converted it to vb.net) but it returns an empty string even though a value was typed into field. Dim test2 As String = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form("txtFirst1"))

Comment: Gives me an "Identifier Expected" error at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is finally working now. Deleted everything and re-enterd code. Not sure if I had a typo or if it was a case sensitive issue. For VB.NET, I used: Dim MyTest As String = Request.Form("firstName1")